# Running my own version of WordCount.java in Hadoop-2.6.0

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, mapreduce, word-count

I am trying to create my own version of wordcount and execute it. For that, I am trying to create the wordcount.jar by executing the following command (as described here http://cs.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Hadoop_Tutorial_1_--_Running_WordCount for previous releases than Hadoop-2.*):

```
javac -classpath /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/*:/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/* -d wordcount_classes/ WordCount.java
jar -cvf wordcount.jar -C wordcount_classes/ .
```

The problem is that I get errors in the first command when trying to compile the wordcount class. In the first command I try to include all the jars that exist in the common and mapreduce directories, because I don't find any jar that has the name "hadoop-0.19.2-core.jar" as described in tutorials I found in the internet for the hadoop-0.*

```
 javac -classpath /home/hadoop/hadoop/hadoop-0.19.2-core.jar -d wordcount_classes WordCount.java
```

When I execute the given wordcount as follows, it works perfect, but I can't compile my own version:

```
 hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-*-examples-2.6.0.jar wordcount input output
```

I've searched in the internet but I find most of tutorials are for Hadoop-1.* which is different from the 2.6.0 version which does not contain any java source file such as the wordcount.java I need, and also has a completely different structure. Hence, I was obliged to download the wordcount.java file separately from https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/examples/WordCount.java
and copy the WordCount.java in the current directory where I execute my commands to create the jar.

I've downloaded Hadoop from this source http://mirror.its.dal.ca/apache/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.6.0/

Here is the details of the errors I get:

```
  /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar(org  /apache/hadoop/fs/Path.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'value()' in type 'LimitedPrivate': class file for org.apache.hadoop.classification.InterfaceAudience not found
  WordCount.java:54: error: cannot access Options
String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
                     ^
class file for org.apache.commons.cli.Options not found
WordCount.java:68: error: method waitForCompletion in class Job cannot be applied to given types;
System.exit(job.waitForCompletion() ? 0 : 1);
               ^
required: boolean
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
Note: WordCount.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
2 errors
1 warning
```

Here is also the WordCount.java :

```
//package org.apache.hadoop.examples;
package org.myorg;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

public class WordCount {

public static class TokenizerMapper 
   extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
private Text word = new Text();

public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
  while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
    word.set(itr.nextToken());
    context.write(word, one);
   }
 }
}

public static class IntSumReducer 
   extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, 
                   Context context
                   ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  int sum = 0;
  for (IntWritable val : values) {
    sum += val.get();
  }
  result.set(sum);
  context.write(key, result);
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
if (otherArgs.length != 2) {
  System.err.println("Usage: wordcount <in> <out>");
  System.exit(2);
}
Job job = new Job(conf, "word count");
job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));
System.exit(job.waitForCompletion() ? 0 : 1);
 }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I updated my question to be more concise. The problem is that I can't compile my own version where I've slightly changed the original code. I think there is a problem with the jars I provide in the command. I also haven't found any wordcount.java file in the hadoop I downloaded so I've downloaded the source code for wordcount.java my self, that's why I think there could be also a problem using it. I don't know if there is any java code in the 2.6.0 version, because bizarrely I haven't found any and no one talks about this  in tutos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by doing the following (It is even easier now with Hadoop-2.6.0) (see this tutorial for more details http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Usage):

- Add the following to your ~/.profile file (don't forget to execute "source  ~/.profile" afterwards):

  export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default

  export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

  export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar # This is very important to facilitate compilation of your java classes.
- I then compile WordCount.java and create a jar:

  $ bin/hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main WordCount.java

  $ jar cf wc.jar WordCount*.class
- Then just use a command like this to execute your job:

  $ hadoop jar wc.jar  WordCount INPUT/ OUTPUT/

Answer (score 1):

This looks more like a Java problem than a Hadoop problem to me. I would recommend to use Eclipse and [Hadoop Developer Tools](http://hdt.incubator.apache.org/%20%22Haddop%20Developer%20Tools) that works with Hadoop version 2.2.0. (unless you specifally need 2.6.0).

Also you may try the %HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\mapreduce\hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-*version_number*.jar

Also the first error message you get at line 54 may be resolved by implementing `org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool` [Class info for Tool](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/Tool.html)
I found this info at [Apache docs on options](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CommandsManual.html).

At line 68 it you're missing an argument for the `job.waitForCompletion()` method call. I would suggest to pass a `true` argument to this method.

Comment: But I think it is already included since with the * wildcard in /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/* it will include al jars in the mapreduce directory and its subdirectories, isn't it ?

Comment: Including the jar to the compiling process is not the same as implementing / extending an interface/class. Implementing the Tool interface means that you actually fill the method stubs with code telling your program how to process the command line arguments.You're also telling the compiler where to look for certain methods.

Answer (score 1):

I solved adding to my WordCount project the jar located in: share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
javac --classpath `hadoop classpath` .... (rest of command)
```

Test on ubuntu and debian.

This work fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

there is small correction at System.exit(job.waitForCompletion() ? 0 : 1);
it should be like this System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
because it will return boolean value..